# kendo treelist expand event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my Kendo UI treelist, I'd like to capture the currently-expanded row in the `expand` event, then check if its children rows are leaf nodes.
If they are leaf nodes, I'd like to remove the `font-weight: bold;` style attribute.

Here is a snippet showing the `treeOptions` object. At this `expand` event, it's easy to know that there are children nodes, but how can I tell if those children nodes has have children or not ? i.e. are they leaf nodes ?

```js
 var treeOptions = {
                dataSource: ds,
                columns: colDefs,
                selectable: true,                   
                height: 320,
                change: function (e) {                    
                    var selectedRow = this.select();
                    var row = this.dataItem(selectedRow);                    
                },
                expand: function (e) {
                  var row = e.model;
                  var hasChildren = row.hasChildren;
                  var uid = row.uid;
                }
            };
```

And here is the Kendo API doc I'm reading through.

thanks in advance,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. Get the dataSource view and iterate through all the rows. Find the ones whose parentid is equal to the current row id and use the uid to update the DOM element:

```
expand: function (e) {
  var id = e.model.id;
  if (!e.model.hasChildren) return; 

  var dataSourceView = $(this)[0].dataSource._view;
  for (var i=0; i<dataSourceView.length; i++){
    var pid =  dataSourceView[i].parentId;

    var Children = dataSourceView[i].hasChildren;
    if (pid == id && !Children){                              
         var uid = dataSourceView[i].uid;
       $('[data-uid="' + uid + '"]').css("font-weight", "bold");
    }

  }
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/imaBi)**

Comment: oh no i forgot to add the style :D, btw nice

Comment: @machun, thanks. plus 1 to you too; looks like we had the same idea.

Comment: good ideas. I was also thinking about the dataSource, but I didn't want to iterate from the top. I was hoping I could somehow parse only the children of my currently-expanded row.

Comment: @ezanker i dont think kendo want to add new function for that, so probably this is good enough. but if the data is huge i wonder if it become slow?

Comment: FYI: I've already made my first column bold by default in the `headerAttributes` of the column definitions. My original post said that I need to remove the bold setting. However, I noticed the `<td>` still has the bold font after applying the `css()` method above. That line is affecting only the `<tr>` style.

Comment: please see `script.js` at http://plnkr.co/edit/HVLG60ttYNH3VHqqeDwA?p=preview , and the `expand:` event of `$scope.treelistOptions`

Comment: @bob, the attributes are applied to the TD not TR, so use $('[data-uid="' + uid + '"] td').css("font-weight", "normal");  Updated DEMO:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/imaBi

Comment: okay that worked. I was trying `$('[data-uid="' + uid + '"]').find('td').css(..)`, which did nothing.

Comment: it works in my plunk, but in my project it doesn't work. I can debug and see the element's css change, however it goes back to bold in the end. Very strange. There's also a Kendo UI scripting error I can't get rid of in my angular project `Cannot read property 'find' of null` , after the `expand` method is through. This error has always occurred though in the Kendo UI source (but not online).

Comment: @bob : could you solve this issue? I have a similar issue where i am trying to change background color of the child elements. If you have found a fix, please do share.

Comment: @user2439903 - see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789095/kendo-ui-grid-rowtemplate-how-to-make-a-function-call

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any method to do that in the doc either, the only way i can think of it right now is by looping through datasource and get the all of the children element that match the parent id of the expanded element. Then you can see if it's 'hasChildren' attribute.

```
expand: function(e) {
  //get the widget datasource then loop to match the parent id of the expanded element
  var data =this.dataSource.data();
  var children = [];
  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      if(data[i].parentId == e.model.id){
      children.push(data[i]);
    }
  }


  //do chose which children you want to see its "hasChildrenStatus"
  console.log(children[0].hasChildren);
  console.log(children[1].hasChildren);

  //do remove css by using it's uid to get the element

}
```

[Kendo dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ONIhu)

Answer (score 0):

if you make the treelist selectable, than you can use the click event

```
$("#treeList).on("click","tr[role='row']",function(e){
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr[role='row']");
        })
```