# Kendo UI grid rowTemplate - calling a function to affect the css of td cells

Tags: kendo-grid

My Kendo UI grid is dynamic, where the columns can be defined as `field0`, `field1` through `field[n]` ; I do NOT know the **number** of fields ahead of time.

I would like to use the `rowTemplate` in order to apply css `background-color` to the `<td>` cell.

***Further details:***

Each cell value must be sent to a ratio function (i.e. the financial risk exposure divided by a benchmark value). The result of that ratio determines the background-color property from that cell).

I'm starting with this code snippet, and I am working on this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wAeJZz8xGeNupsA3rVMA?p=preview

```js
var gridOptions = {
 dataSource: ds,
 pageable: true,
 columnMenu: true,
 resizable: true,
 columns: heatMapColDefs ,
 dataBound: function (e) {
 }
 , rowTemplate: function (row) {
  // HOW TO DETERMINE THE TD CELL VALUE AND APPLY A BACKGROUND-COLOR DYNAMICALLY ???
 }
};
```

Your advice is appreciated...

Bob

Comment: If you don't know the fields ahead of time, you need to iterate the first row of the datasource to find all the field keys and build the columns, fields, and row template:  http://plnkr.co/edit/9Yv2agLQnVJNVoLI8HjR?p=preview

Comment: I already have the columns array built out ahead of time, but I don't know the NUMBER of fields ahead of time. So I would need to grab each <tr> row, then iterate the <td> cells. that's where I'm stuck. I'll check your plunk...thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the first row of data from the datasource, you can iterate the properties to get all the fields and build dynamically the columns and row template of the grid and the model fields of the dataSource:

```
var ColsFieldsRowTemplate = {}
  function GetRowTemplate(){
    var obj = {};
    var columns= [];
    var fields = {};


    var t = '<tr data-uid="#= uid #">';
    //use first row of data to get the fields
    var row = myData[0];
    for (var key in row) {
      if (key == 'field0'){
        fields[key] = { type: "string" };
        columns.push({"field": key});
        t += '<td >#= ' + key  + '  #</td>';
      } else if (key.indexOf("field") > -1){
        fields[key] = { type: "number" };
        columns.push({"field": key});
        t += '<td style="background-color: #=' + key + ' > 3000000 ? "red" : "green" #;">#= ' + key  + '  #</td>';
      }
    }
    t += '</tr>';

    ColsFieldsRowTemplate.rowTemplate = t;
    ColsFieldsRowTemplate.cols = columns;
    ColsFieldsRowTemplate.fields = fields;
    console.log(ColsFieldsRowTemplate);
    return ColsFieldsRowTemplate;
  }
  GetRowTemplate();

  vm.userGridOptions = {
            selectable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,       
            rowTemplate: ColsFieldsRowTemplate.rowTemplate,
            columns: ColsFieldsRowTemplate.cols,
            editable: {
                mode: "popup"
                //template: kendo.template($("#editorTemplate").html())   // loaded up in index.html (alt. kendo.template('<div>..</div>') )                
            },
            toolbar: ["create"]
  };


  // DEFINE DATA SOURCE FOR USER KRIs
  vm.gridDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({  // customized User KRI grid; pull from server or localStorage            
      pageSize: 10,
      transport: {
          read: function(options){
            options.success(myData)
          }
      },            
      schema: {
          model: {
              id: "id",
              fields: ColsFieldsRowTemplate.fields
          }
      }            
  });
```

> Updated **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Yv2agLQnVJNVoLI8HjR?p=preview)**

Comment: I've come up with another way of building the `rowTemplate`. It's less efficient, but it enables me to drill into the cell values for each row and call my `calculateColor` routine accordingly: http://plnkr.co/edit/wAeJZz8xGeNupsA3rVMA?p=preview . My custom function in script.js is called `buildRowTemplate(data) `, just below your `getTemplate()` routine .

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be hard to sync the columns with the column headers if you use a row template. What I'd do is use a dynamically created client template and place the business logic inside that one instead.

```
 function getTemplate(field, fieldName){

    var color;

    if(field[fieldName] > 4000000){
      color = "green";
    }else{
      color = "red";
    }

    return "<span style='background-color: " + color + "'>" + field[fieldName] + "</span>";
  }

  vm.userGridOptions = {
            selectable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,       
            columns: [
              { field: "field0" },
              { field: "field1", 
                template: (function(dataItem){

                   return getTemplate(dataItem, "field1");
                  }) 
              },
```

Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lPUzfu?p=preview